# Line break in css animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm creating an animation but I can't seem to get it all to display on the same line. One word works fine but, as soon as I put a space between the words it goes to the next line, even without `<br>`

```
.autotype {overflow:hidden;} 

.autotype {animation: 
autotype 3s steps(10, end); 
animation-iteration-count: 
infinite;} 

@keyframes autotype 
{from{width:0px;}} 

@keyframes autotype { 0%. 
{width: 0px;} 20%{width: 
20px;}40%{ width: 40px;}
60%{wdith: 60px;} 80%{width: 
80px;} 100%{width: 100px;}}

<div class="autotype">ydydy 
gggf</div>
```

So how do I get it to continue on the same line and put a break in when I want?

Comment: Try to add white-space: nowrap to .autotype

Comment: Thanks but it's not sequencial. I've managed to break the lines up but it's displaying them all at the same time instead of sequencially.